# Why jQuery selectable is not functioning properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-selectable

I have an mvc project where I have implemented two jQuery selectable plugin like below:
The `<HTML>` code,

```
<div class="product-page-options">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <label class="control-label" style="font-weight:bolder">Size:</label>
                                    <ol class="ui-selectable" style="width:auto" id="selectable">
                                        @{
                                            var size = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',');
                                            foreach (var item in size)
                                            {
                                                <li class="ui-selectable">@item</li>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <label class="control-label">Color:</label>
                                    <ol class="ui-selectable" style="width:auto" id="selectable1">

                                        @{
                                            var color = Model.AvailableColors.Split(',');
                                            foreach (var clr in color)
                                            {
                                                <li class="ui-selectable">@clr</li>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The static script for selectable jQuery plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectable").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.selected).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
                $("#selectedsize").val($("li.ui-selected").html());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectable1").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ci) {
                $(ci.selected).siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
                $("#selectedsize").val($("li.ui-selected").html());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first selectable jQuery plugin works perfectly while the second is not functioning properly. I mean I cannot select any item from the second `selectable` list and also the appearance is not same as the first one. The picture below shows clearly the problem.
[image: Selectable Details Image]

Anything i can do about it? any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why two `script` and `ready` functions? you may write like this: `$("#selectable, #selectable1").selectable({...})`

Comment: You are setting $("#selectedsize") in the color selector.  This may be your error.

Comment: @Riad I tried the suggested way but no better outcome all is the same again.

Comment: @RichLinnell that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 issues at play here.  Firstly, you will need to have styles set up specifically for both of the selectables (if you have based your code on the examples on the jQuery UI site.  Secondly, upon selecting in the selector for the items, you will need to identify the path to the selected li element as a child of the relevant selectable.

`$("#selectedcolor").val($("#selectable1>li.ui-selected").html());`

The following plunker will show you it working :

[Link To My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zquXmY5FrTDmmvV5HeOq?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks will try this!